# Did Rousseau say that equality of conditions is not possible without slavery?

Tags: politics, quotes

I just read *[What is Property](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/360/360-h/360-h.htm)*, written [in 1840](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Property%3F) by [Pierre-Joseph Proudhon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Joseph_Proudhon).

At the end of the book he attributes a paraphrased quote to [Jean-Jaques Rousseau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Jacques_Rousseau):

> The communistic republic of Plato involved slavery; that of Lycurgus employed Helots, whose duty it was to produce for their masters, thus enabling the latter to devote themselves exclusively to athletic sports and to war. *Even J. J. Rousseau—confounding communism and equality—has said somewhere that, without slavery, he did not think equality of conditions possible.*

Did J.J. Rousseau really say slavery was a necessary condition to reach equality of conditions?

Comment: This might be better suited for Philosophy.SE.

Comment: What "conditions"?

Comment: I think "Equality of conditions" means equality of opportunities and access to a work that provide decent salary.